# ReflectionException with Symfony and Sonata, "Class does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm experiencing a problem trying to fit my Entities in the Sonata Admin Bundle. I have something like 5 entities, which are finely listed and viewed in the bundle, but I cannot edit or create a new entry.

When I try to edit or create, I get a `ReflectionException` error:

> Class does not exist

I tried in order to solve that problem to operate on namespaces (moving controller in the same namespace that Admin files, or so) or to tweak the Admin Controller in order to tell it about my entities ("->add('individual', 'entity', array('class' => 'Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Individual'))" instead of ->add('individual')).

My entity is named Biosample. Here is the Entity file:

```
<?php

namespace Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="biosample")
*/
class Biosample
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Individual", inversedBy="samples")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="individual_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $individual;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
 protected $organ;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
 protected $sample_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $organ_location;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 protected $tissue_type;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $tissue_subtype;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
 */
 protected $sampling_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=3, nullable=true)
 */
 protected $cellularity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $conservation;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="biosamples")
 */
 protected $projects;

 public function __construct()
 {
      $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
 }

 public function __toString()
 {
      return $this->sample_name;
 }

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set organ
 *
 * @param string $organ
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setOrgan($organ)
{
    $this->organ = $organ;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get organ
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getOrgan()
{
    return $this->organ;
}

/**
 * Set organ_location
 *
 * @param string $organLocation
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setOrganLocation($organLocation)
{
    $this->organ_location = $organLocation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get organ_location
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getOrganLocation()
{
    return $this->organ_location;
}

/**
 * Set tissue_type
 *
 * @param string $tissueType
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setTissueType($tissueType)
{
    $this->tissue_type = $tissueType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tissue_type
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTissueType()
{
    return $this->tissue_type;
}

/**
 * Set tissue_subtype
 *
 * @param string $tissueSubtype
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setTissueSubtype($tissueSubtype)
{
    $this->tissue_subtype = $tissueSubtype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tissue_subtype
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTissueSubtype()
{
    return $this->tissue_subtype;
}

/**
 * Set sampling_date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $samplingDate
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setSamplingDate($samplingDate)
{
    $this->sampling_date = $samplingDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sampling_date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getSamplingDate()
{
    return $this->sampling_date;
}

/**
 * Set cellularity
 *
 * @param string $cellularity
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setCellularity($cellularity)
{
    $this->cellularity = $cellularity;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cellularity
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCellularity()
{
    return $this->cellularity;
}

/**
 * Set conservation
 *
 * @param string $conservation
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setConservation($conservation)
{
    $this->conservation = $conservation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get conservation
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getConservation()
{
    return $this->conservation;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set individual
 *
 * @param \Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Individual $individual
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setIndividual(\Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Individual $individual = null)
{
    $this->individual = $individual;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get individual
 *
 * @return \Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Individual 
 */
public function getIndividual()
{
    return $this->individual;
}

/**
 * Add projects
 *
 * @param \Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $projects
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function addProject(\Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $projects)
{
    $this->projects[] = $projects;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove projects
 *
 * @param \Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $projects
 */
public function removeProject(\Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $projects)
{
    $this->projects->removeElement($projects);
}

/**
 * Get projects
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getProjects()
{
    return $this->projects;
}

/**
 * Set sample_name
 *
 * @param string $sampleName
 * @return Biosample
 */
public function setSampleName($sampleName)
{
    $this->sample_name = $sampleName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sample_name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSampleName()
{
    return $this->sample_name;
}
}`
```

Here is my BiosampleAdmin.php:

```
    <?php

namespace Platform\ProjectBundle\Controller\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;

use Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Biosample;

class BiosampleAdmin extends Admin
{

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper $showMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('sample_name')
            ->add('individual', 'entity', array('class' => 'Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Individual'))
            ->add('organ')
            ->add('organ_location')
            ->add('tissue_type')
            ->add('tissue_subtype')
            ->add('sampling_date')
            ->add('cellularity')
            ->add('conservation')
            ->add('projects', 'entity', array('class' => 'Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project'))
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }


    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('sample_name')
                ->add('individual')
                ->add('organ')
                ->add('organ_location')
                ->add('tissue_type')
                ->add('tissue_subtype')
            ->end()
            ->with('Miscelaneous')
                ->add('sampling_date')
                ->add('cellularity')
                ->add('conservation')
            ->end()
            ->with('Projects')
                ->add('projects')
            ->end()
            ->with('Description')
                ->add('description', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => false))
            ->end()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('sample_name')
            ->add('individual')
            ->add('projects')
            ->add('organ')
            ->add('tissue')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }


    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('sample_name')
            ->add('individual')
            ->add('projects')
        ;
    }
}
```

Here is the admin controller:

```
    <?php

namespace Platform\ProjectBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Biosample;

class BiosampleAdminController extends Controller
{

}
```

And if you need it, here my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "~1.2",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "nervo/yuicompressor": "2.4.8",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "~2",
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "~1.1",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my service declaration and my config.yml file:
Service.yml:

```
services:
    platform.project.admin.biosample:
        class: Platform\ProjectBundle\Controller\Admin\BiosampleAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Project Manager, label: Biosample }
        arguments: [null, Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Biosample, PlatformProjectBundle:BiosampleAdmin]
```

Config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }


fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: secured
    user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager


sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    entity_manager: ~

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu: ~
        sonata.user.block.account: ~
        sonata.block.service.text: ~


sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm

mopa_bootstrap:
    form: ~
```

And last but not least: the full stack trace.

```
[1] ReflectionException: Class  does not exist
    at n/a
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6756

    at ReflectionClass->__construct('')
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6756

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagerForClass(null)
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php line 220

    at Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager->getEntityManager(null)
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php line 54

    at Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager->getMetadata(null)
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php line 317

    at Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager->getIdentifierFieldNames(null)
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 12663

    at Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\ChoiceList\ModelChoiceList->__construct(object(ModelManager), null, null, null, null)
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 13690

    at Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType->Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\{closure}(object(OptionsResolver), object(SimpleChoiceList))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php line 836

    at Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver->offsetGet('choice_list')
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php line 769

    at Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver->resolve(array('sonata_field_description' => object(FieldDescription), 'class' => null, 'model_manager' => object(ModelManager), 'multiple' => false, 'label_render' => false, 'label' => 'Description'))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php line 109

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType->createBuilder(object(FormFactory), 'description', array('sonata_field_description' => object(FieldDescription), 'class' => null, 'model_manager' => object(ModelManager), 'multiple' => false, 'label_render' => false, 'label' => 'Description'))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php line 82

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy->createBuilder(object(FormFactory), 'description', array('sonata_field_description' => object(FieldDescription), 'class' => null, 'model_manager' => object(ModelManager), 'multiple' => false, 'label_render' => false, 'label' => 'Description'))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 87

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('description', 'sonata_type_model', null, array('sonata_field_description' => object(FieldDescription), 'class' => null, 'model_manager' => object(ModelManager), 'multiple' => false, 'label_render' => false, 'label' => 'Description'))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 106

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->create('description', 'sonata_type_model', array('sonata_field_description' => object(FieldDescription), 'class' => null, 'model_manager' => object(ModelManager), 'multiple' => false, 'label_render' => false, 'label' => 'Description'))
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 268

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->resolveChildren()
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 216

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 9671

    at Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin->buildForm()
        in /var/www/Project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 9930

    at Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin->getForm()
        in /var/www/Project/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/CRUDController.php line 353

    at Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController->editAction('1')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CRUDController), 'editAction'), array('1'))
        in /var/www/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3022

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /var/www/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2984

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3133

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2377

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /var/www/Project/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Note that [Symphony](http://www.getsymphony.com/) (a PHP CMS) != [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) (a PHP framework).

Comment: Oups, thank you halfer. I will modify the tags right now ! Well, seems like I got them right at the beggining, I am talking about Symfony, the PHP framework.

Comment: Not the tags, the title - fixed `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason for this error was a bad copy/paste from the tutorial.

In the Admin Class, the function configureFormFields contained a field "Description" badly described.

```
->with('Description')
                ->add('description', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => false))
            ->end()
```

I had to replace it to:

```
  ->with('Description')
                ->add('description')
            ->end()
```

I discovered that automatic Admin Class skeleton generation was a function of Sonata Admin Bundle. 
In order to automatically generate, execute:

> php app/console sonata:admin:generate

Then enter the full path to your entity, in this example:

> Platform\ProjectBundle\Entity\Biosample

The admin bundle will parse your entity and :

- Generate the Admin Class file
- Add an entry in your application bundle's service.yml
- Generate optionnaly the CRUD controller

I guess this should be the prefered method when one is starting with sonata admin bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for a reason i ignore, not in the past project where i've done exactly the same...
After an hour of search, i realize my table 'fos_user_user_group' has not been created has the mapping is not created. So my solution was simply to override the groups property of my entity User in order to define the Doctrine ORM Mapping :

```
/**
 * The User can have many groups.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $groups;
```

After that, doctrine:schema:update --force and the problem was solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you did it like me, and created first the database then via the console the yml files and from that the classes, then your annotations are useless.

Sonata is using yml and not annotations. They exist and seem to work but they just don't. To make the "Class does not exist" message go check what you yml definitions are saying. I needed to add the relationships and entity classes there.

If this is really the reason for your errors you might want to activate the annotations by deleting or moving the yml or xml templates somewhere else (..\Resources\config\doctrine).